# How to get the output of command executed using child_process in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I am new to node js, I want to execute a command in node js and want to display the running status of the command to the terminal and also to some log file.

```
// Displaying the output in terminal but I am not able to access child.stdout
const child = spawn(command,[], {
      shell: true,
      cwd: process.cwd(),
      env: process.env,
      stdio: 'inherit',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    });

// Pushing the output to file but not able to do live interaction with terminal
const child = spawn(command,[], {
      shell: true,
      cwd: process.cwd(),
      env: process.env,
      stdio: 'pipe',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    });
```

Is it possible to do both? Please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify separate options for stdin, stdout and stderr:

```js
const child = spawn(command,[], {
      shell: true,
      cwd: process.cwd(),
      env: process.env,
      stdio: ['inherit', 'pipe', 'pipe'],
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    });
```

This way the subprocess inherits stdin and you should be able to interact with it. The subprocess uses pipes for stdout (and stderr) and you can write the output to a file. Because output is not sent to the terminal by the subprocess, you need to write the output to the terminal yourself. This can easily be done by piping:

```js
// Pipe child stdout to process stdout (terminal)...
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

// ...and do something else with the data.
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => ...);
```

This probably only works correctly if the subprocess is a simple command line program and does not have an advanced text-based UI.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem here is for example the command I am running is asking for some inputs like: ``` Enter your name: <Then we should enter the name from terminal> Enter your age: <Then we should enter the age from terminal>``` In these cases, it's not showing the ```Enter your name and Enter your age ``` because we are piping stdout.

Comment: Here I can use ```stdio: 'inherit',``` this, but I want to read the entire data in terminal, Is it possible to get the data that is in terminal after the command execution?

Comment: Yes, you are piping stdout so you need to write the data to the terminal yourself.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an exampe of how the handle the child stdout.

Comment: But this will not give the interactiveness with the terminal right? The same example I mentioned above ```Enter your name``` will be output to the terminal once the command execution is done but not in between the command execution.

Comment: No, this should work. I have tested it by spawning `npm init`.

Comment: This is the sample script I am using ``` #!/bin/bash```
```read -p "Enter Your Name: "  username```
```echo "Welcome $username!"``` running command as sh input.sh, but it is not asking ```Enter Your Name:``` in the terminal but taking the username and printing it in terminal(```Welcome $username!```).

Comment: That is because `read -p` outputs to stderr, not stdout. You need to also pipe stderr or use `echo -n "Enter your name: "` for the prompt.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot.